# Bounded operator on weakly convergent sequence maps to weakly convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $H, K$ are Hilbert Spaces. We have a sequence $v_n\in H$ that converges weakly to some vector $v\in H$, that is:
$$\langle v_n - v, w\rangle \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n\to\infty$$
Also, we know that the operator $T:H \to K$ is bounded.
I need to show that the sequence $Tv_n\in K$ converges weakly to $Tv\in K$.

**My Proof**

I tried proving it like this:
Let $\epsilon>0$. Then since $v_n$ converges weakly to $v$ we have that there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$n>n_0 \Longrightarrow |\langle v_n-v, w\rangle | < \epsilon $$
Now, let $z\in K$:
\begin{align}
|\langle Tv_n-Tv, z\rangle| &= |\langle T(v_n-v), z\rangle| && \text{as $T$ is linear}\\
&= |\langle v_n-v, T^*z\rangle| && \text{as every bounded operator has a unique adjoint $T^*$}\\
&< \epsilon && \text{as $v_n$ converges weakly to $v$}
\end{align}

Is this okay?

Comment: Actually, I think it is all wrong cause I am assuming it is linear

Comment: The term 'bounded operator' usually refers to a linear and continuous map. So your argument is fine.